# Regex for matching a word, unless the previous line ends with a word

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I have a text which contains many sentences, separated by newlines and arbitrary whitespace:

```
Some thing.
  Some other text.
 Some line.
   Some additional text.
Some stuff.
    Some additional text.
Some additional text.
```

How do I match only those `Some` words, where the previous line doesn't end with `thing` or `stuff`?

For the example above, I would match these words:

```
Some thing.           
  Some other text.          <-- skip, previous line ends with "thing."
 [Some] line.
   [Some] additional text.  
[Some] stuff.
    Some additional text.   <-- skip, previous line ends with "stuff."
[Some] additional text.
```

I tried `(?<!thing\.|stuff\.)[\r\n\s]+Some`, but I don't know how to include the whitespace+newlines in the negative lookbehind? I've found some examples using `\K` to allow "variable length" matching, but I obviously don't understand how `\K` at all, since I wasn't able to match anything.

Comment: What about the `Some` at the very beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a '[sacrificial match](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)' with a non-capturing group to match what you don't want which then allows matching what you do want in a capturing group:

```
/(?:^\s*Some.*(?:thing\.|stuff\.)\s*^\s*Some)|(^\s*Some)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKohOt/2/)

Or, if you want the first and the fourth (as stated in comments, your example is inconsistent...)

```
/(?:(?:thing\.|stuff\.)\s*Some)|(^\s*Some)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R17vp8/1/)

Or, skip the first `Some` and include the fourth:

```
/(?:(?:thing\.|stuff\.)\s*Some)|((?<=\n)\s*Some)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4LJJy/2/)

This method works on most regex flavors.

A negative look behind is a problem in this case because a look behind needs to be fixed width. The `\s*` you describe is not fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to fail a known matcha and use in alternation use your match:

```
(?:thing|stuff)\.\R\s*\w+(*SKIP)(*F)|\bSome\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/34eN8c/2)

Here `(?:thing|stuff)\.\R\s*.*(*SKIP)(*F)` will skip & fail the match when previous line ends with `thing.` or `stuff.`. In the right hand side of alternation we will just get our match.